# work with mysql array data in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress

how to convert array data to work with it in this case? especially in wordpress.
when i print the results i get stdClass Object.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [posts_id] => 336
            [value] => 8
            [count(*)] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [posts_id] => 329
            [value] => 2
            [count(*)] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [posts_id] => 327
            [value] => 3
            [count(*)] => 1
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [posts_id] => 338
            [value] => 1
            [count(*)] => 1
        )

)
```

and this is my query

```
   <?php global $wpdb;

$test = $wpdb->get_results('select
    posts_id,
    value,
    count(*)
From
    wp_mrp_rating_item_entry_value
group by
    posts_id,
    value
order by
    count(*) desc'); 
echo '<pre>';
print_r($test);
echo '</pre>';
```

How can i get the data out of this array to save into another database table? Or how can i at least save the single values into variables for every id? I tried allot but i have no idea yet so i hope someone is knowing it better than me? thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you mean save data in other table ? `INSERT` maybe?

Comment: @Raptor oh yepp i ment save. my fold.  any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
foreach($test as $item) :

$ID = $item->posts_id; 
var_dump($ID); //test variable


//if you want to place into the db 

   //DB CODE>>>

$firstName = "Dylan"  //example of field in db to change
$LastName =  "bloggs" //example of second field in db to change

$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
 "
  INSERT INTO $wpdb->name_of_wp_table_goes_here
  ( name_of_field_goes_here )
  VALUES ( %d, %s, $s ) 
 ", 
    $ID,
    $field
) );

   //<<<DB END

endforeach;
```

Remove the DB code if you want to manually store into a database.

You could also access other keys the same way. e.g., $value = $item->value; -- you would place this in the foreach loop and continue.

Comment: thanks u so much. thats perfect. there are so many helpful and working answers here. yours is fitting exactly. made my day.  thanks to you and the other guys. regards form Berlin

Answer (score 1):

```
//Just use type cast brother. Use

$test = (array) $test;

//print_r($test);

foreach($test as $item) :

//if you want to place into the db 
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
    "INSERT INTO $wpdb->name_of_wp_table_goes_here
        ( post_id,value,count )
        VALUES (".$item['post_id'].", '".$item['value']."', ".$item['count'].")
    %d",  
    1
) );

endforeach;
```

Comment: OP wants to save the data to another table.

Comment: thanks mate.now i get the whole array but how would i use the single values of the array (like $ID = .... ; $value=....; $count =...; now to work with it.i need to update(or save it into) another table. i need this for every id. so i guess its have to be within a loop. !? thanks

Comment: have a last question: how would i do to get just the highest value of (count)? MAX() seems not to work on count(*) in the query, any idea??

Answer (score 1):

In Wordpress when you use get_results you can choose de hydration mode :

> **output_type** 
>   One of three pre-defined constants. Defaults to OBJECT.
>   OBJECT - result will be output as an object.
>   ARRAY_A - result will be output as an associative array.
>   ARRAY_N - result will be output as a numerically indexed array.

So if you do :

```
$test = $wpdb->get_results('select
posts_id,
value,
count(*)
From
wp_mrp_rating_item_entry_value
group by
posts_id,
value
order by
count(*) desc', ARRAY_N);
```

You should get an array as result.

Answer (score 1):

As this is array of objects, you can use simple foreach to access your values:

```
<?php
    foreach ($test as $t) {
        $t->post_id;
        $t->value;
        // You can insert your values in different table here
    }
?>
```

For count you can change a bit your query to:

```
SELECT posts_id, value, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM
    wp_mrp_rating_item_entry_value
GROUP BY
    posts_id,
    value
ORDER BY
    COUNT(*) DESC
```

so your count in foreach-loop will be accessible $t->cnt.

Comment: have a last question: how would i do to get just the highest value of (cnt)? MAX() seems not to work on count(*) in the query, any idea??  thank u

Answer (score 1):

Well you have an array of objects, which is a very nice contruct. All you need to do is process over the array.

I cannot help you with the WordPress mechanisms for a table insert but the pseudo code would be something like this.

First it would be a good idea to give the count a more usable name

```
$test = $wpdb->get_results('select
    posts_id, value,count(*) as how_many
From wp_mrp_rating_item_entry_value
group by
    posts_id, value
order by count(*) desc');
```

Now process each occurance of the array of objects

```
foreach ($test as $obj) {
    // Use these fields in an Insert statement
    $sql = "INSERT INTO TableName (f1,f2,f3)
            VALUES ({$obj->post_id}, 
                    {$obj->value}, 
                    {$obj->how_many}");
    // WP command to issue a query
}
```

Comment: thanks mate this is working great for my purpose with a wp modification.

Comment: im using it like that now  foreach ($test as $obj) {
    $wpdb->insert( 
 'Toplist', 
 array( 
  'postid' => $obj->posts_id, 
  'category' => $obj->value,
  'votingcount' => $obj->how_many
 ), 
 array( 
  '%d', 
  '%s',
  '%s' 
 ) 
);     thanks again   u re awesome.

Comment: have a last question: how would i do to get just the highest value of (how_many)?  MAX() seems not to work on count(*) in the query, any idea??

Comment: JImmy, you should really ask another question if you have another question.